# Cypher/Neo4j Query To Get Info Of Currect Node and Others Related With That

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a social media scenario as seen in image([Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKFAn.png)) and wanted to create newsfeed for a user which will include **posts** of the nodes he is **following** and also his own posts.
and for that I was using this cypher query :

```
MATCH (:User{id: "MThIs8ibezSjylKBxux7qdusDyu1"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(b) WITH b.id
as uids 
MATCH (u:User) -[:POSTED]-> (p:Post) 
WHERE  u.id in uids 
OR u.id in ["MThIs8ibezSjylKBxux7qdusDyu1"] 
RETURN p.caption , p.timeStamp ,p.linksArray , p.postId ORDER BY p.timeStamp DESC
```

this works perfectly fine unless a scenario occurs where the **current node** does not **follow** anyone [Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ct3o.png).

Now Logically it should return the posts of the current node too but that's not the case.If the user is following someone it returns posts from both of them but if the user is following no one it returns nothing.
As I'm new to neo4j I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MATCH indicates that the user MUST follow someone. If they don't they are filtered out. So if that pattern is not a requirement, use an [OPTIONAL MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/) instead of a MATCH.